# Comparison chart for glyphs that work in MS Word, Illustrator, InDesign+

Tags: fonts, tools

I want to buy some fonts and ran across an excellent comparison chart for the advance glyphs and ligatures available in the various programs such as Word, Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign and so on.

Of course, out of the hundreds if not thousand screenshots and bookmarks for everything else, I can't find this chart.

It was important as I remember a lot of the ligatures and glyphs were not supported in Word and I remember thinking "Oh Lord, I will have to buy and learn a new program!"

Which I of course do not want to do. But I don't want to buy one of the fonts such as Adobe Jenson, Garamond or Arno Pro (or others along those lines). I'm looking for a font with beautiful glyphs and ligatures in particular.

Does anyone know of this chart I am talking about?

Does anyone know of a font I could use with these characteristics in MS Word for Mac 2011?